# visual studio azure db view that allows updating

Tags: visual-studio, view, azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-sql-database

doing this - in the server explorer of visual studio 2012:

- adding the connection to the azure sql database
- opening that connection node
- navigating to view
- right clicking and selecting new view
- copy/paste a query
- execute

get result as a single entry!

however, it is read only, meaning - can not edit it and update directly from this view.

this used to work in previous visual studio and mssql database.

is this a bug, feature, etc? and how to have the behaviour from previous visual studio (where if you can remember there was a visual designer of a view that had this capability)? want to execute a select query, get some results that are then in-place editable and will perform an update on the database.

thnx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Editing results of a query never worked, neither from SQL Management Studio or other tools.  What has worked and continues to work in VS2012 is editing data from a table:

Navigate to the desired table, right-click and choose "Show Table Data".  This data is editable, provided your account has permissions.

HTH

Comment: not true. i have seen it work. your suggestion is fine but it takes a long time to transfer a huge table simply to edit one arbitrary line. if i really have to i will install an old visual studio somewhere and make a screenshot :P to prove it, but it's a hassle :P what does HTH mean btw?

Comment: i played arround some more and i remembered that in previous visual studio there was a kind of visual designer of a view that allowed dragging and dropping tables and had a sort of three part view and in it one could visual design a query and there i think it was possible...